# Puppet Enterprise-no implicit conversion of nil into String

Tags: puppet, puppet-enterprise

I know nothing about Ruby, just started exploring Puppet and want to create custom fact, for a start, used fact found on internet to see how it works:

copied code below to `/etc/puppetlabs/code/environments/production/modules/dsc/lib/facter/windows.rb` (dsc is module name)

```
Facter.add(:ismsclusternode) do  
  confine :kernel => 'windows'

  sysnativedir = Facter.value(:system32)
  setcode do
    if Facter::Util::Resolution.exec(sysnativedir +
        '\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\powershell.exe "(get-windowsfeature 
        -Name Failover-Clustering).Installed"') == "True"
      true
    else
      false
    end
  end
end
```

from agent output:

```
Info: Facter: loading custom facts from C:/ProgramData\PuppetLabs\puppet\cache\lib\facter\windows.rb.
Debug: Facter: executing command: C:\Windows\system32\cmd.exe /c C:\Windows\System32\Wbem\wmic.exe ComputerSystem get SystemType | FindStr /i x
Debug: Facter: x64-based PC
Debug: Facter: process exited with exit code 0.
Debug: Facter: searching for custom facts in C:/ProgramData\PuppetLabs\puppet\cache\lib\facter.
Debug: Facter: custom fact "common_appdata" was not found.
Error: Facter: error while resolving custom fact "_puppet_inventory_1": no implicit conversion of nil into String
Debug: Facter: fact "_puppet_inventory_1" resolved to null and will not be added.
Error: Facter: error while resolving custom fact "_puppet_inventory_1": no implicit conversion of nil into String
Error: Failed to apply catalog: Parameter path failed on File[/PuppetLabs/pxp-agent/etc/pxp-agent.conf]: File paths must be fully qualified, not '/PuppetLabs/pxp-agent/etc/pxp-agent.conf' (file: /opt/puppetlabs/puppet/modules/puppet_enterprise/manifests/pxp_agent.pp, line: 87)
```

/opt/puppetlabs/puppet/modules/puppet_enterprise/manifests/pxp_agent.pp, line: 87

```
file { "${puppet_enterprise::params::pxp_agent_etc}/pxp-agent.conf":


puppetserver version: 2018.1.0.54
 puppet --version
5.5.2
```

Comment: The error is for the fact `_puppet_inventory_1`, but the code shown is for `ismsclusternode`. Is there a reason to believe the two are connected?

Comment: no, i'm getting same error no matter which ruby code i'm running

Comment: Have you actually purchased Puppet Enterprise?  That would entitle you to support.  You are free to ask here in any case, but the issue appears to revolve around some PE-specific bits, and those are not as well covered here as the bits that are also in OS Puppet.

Comment: Not yet, we still evaluate it.